Is it a sin if my parents arent talking to me right now?
Aslamualaikum brother or sister, I would like to know if my parents aren't talking to me right now is it a sin for me?
Recently an incident happened where my father sweared at me and told me to get up when I was doing so, so in reply all I said was "swearing is haram and you shouldn't do so" he replied with "so now you think I'm a sinner" after that he stopped talking to me. I later apologized even though I think I'm not wrong. My father then replied with "sorry doesnt do anything, you've said what you wanted to say". Then after he just stopped fully talking to me. I say salaam to him whenever he leaves the house or comes back but he doesnt acknowledge my presences at all.
I just want to know am i getting sins for this, or is my father wrong here.
Jazakallah

Everyone is a sinner, I don't get what he's trying to say. If all you say is true and there is no further context outside of this, then this is a weird manipulation tactic from him but I am glad you have maintained your respect and caring attitude towards him and you must continue to do so.
